# C++ I/O don't understand why there is -1

Tags: c++

I am simply trying to read each character from a file and print them in the screen.
For testing, I tried to print ascii value in a console screen first before printing characters.

the content of the file I am trying to read is below:

```
assign1_2.cpp:33:20: error: cannot convert 'std::string 
    {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' 
    to 'int atoi(const char*)'
```

I used the code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void CountLetters(string filename);

int main()
{
        CountLetters("count.txt");
}

void CountLetters(string filename)
{
    cout << filename << endl;

    ifstream in;
    in.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
    vector<char> letter;
    char temp;
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        cout << in.get() << endl;
    }

    in.close();

}
```

After running these code and I see  "-1" at the end in the console screen.
Anyone please explain? thanks

Comment: Well, what's in `count.txt`? You might as well actually have a `-1` in it!

Comment: How is the compiler-error you posted related?

Comment: Did you debug the method step by step? Have a look into all variables and see if the "-1" happens in a `cout <<` or as the return value of main.

Comment: count.txt contains this: 

assign1_2.cpp:33:20: error: cannot convert 'std::string 
    {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' 
    to 'int atoi(const char*)'

thanks

Comment: @Martin well, the function return is void. so I assume cout does not have anything to do with it? I am a newbie to C++ so I am sorry I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Martin: The `main()` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it should `return 0;` according to the C++ standard. Unless this isn't the OP's actual code.

Comment: Remember, `in.eof()` is only true *after* you have reached EOF. `in.get()` will return -1 when you have reached EOF.(and only after that, in.eof() will be true).

Answer (score 14):

**Do not read while not `eof()`**<sup>1</sup>. That's not a proper reading loop.

Read **while reading succeeds**.

```
int x;
while ((x = in.get()) != EOF)
{
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Testing for `in.eof()` will not guarantee reading will succeed. When you test for `in.eof()` you're actually testing if *the previous read operation tried to read past the end of the file*. This is bad, because it means the *previous read operation failed*. It failed and you didn't care, and just pressed on to use the value it returned *even though it failed*.

When `in.get()` fails, it returns the constant `EOF`. That's what you should be checking. If `in.get()` fails, you don't want to continue with your loop as if it succeeded.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Same goes for while `good()` or while not `bad()`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have a question though. Many of examples seem to have eof for ending the loop. why do you say that it is not a proper way? thanks

Comment: @user1047092: What are these examples you refer to? A lot of examples on the World Wide Web (and some books!) are simply crap. Take a look at [the C++ tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) here on Stack Overflow for resources with good C++ examples.

Comment: @user1047092 I added an explanation. The sad truth is, lots of examples you can find around are just plain wrong. I really can't understand why people insist on that kind of loops. As you realized, some simple test will immediately show it's not correct.

Comment: +1 for insightful explanation. Never knew many examples out there are wrong.