# Reading a single character from an fstream?

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, fstream

I'm trying to move from stdio to iostream, which is proving very difficult.  I've got the basics of loading a file and closing them, but I really don't have a clue as to what a stream even is yet, or how they work.

In stdio everything's relatively easy and straight forward compared to this.  What I need to be able to do is

1. Read a single character from a text file.
2. Call a function based on what that character is.
3. Repeat till I've read all the characters in the file.

What I have so far is.. not much:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream("sometextfile.txt", std::ios::in);
    // this is SUPPOSED to be the while loop for reading.  I got here and realized I have 
    //no idea how to even read a file
    while()
    {
    }
return 0;
}
```

What I need to know is how to get a single character and how that character is actually stored(Is it a string? An int?  A char?  Can I decide for myself how to store it?)

Once I know that I think I can handle the rest.  I'll store the character in an appropriate container, then use a switch to do things based on what that character actually is.  It'd look something like this.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream textFile("sometextfile.txt", std::ios::in);

    while(..able to read?)
    {
        char/int/string readItem;
        //this is where the fstream would get the character and I assume stick it into readItem?
        switch(readItem)
        {
        case 1:
            //dosomething
              break;
        case ' ':
            //dosomething etc etc
              break;
        case '\n':
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Notice that I need to be able to check for white space and new lines, hopefully it's possible.  It would also be handy if instead of one generic container I could store numbers in an int and chars in a char.  I can work around it if not though.

Thanks to anyone who can explain to me how streams work and what all is possible with them.

Comment: The method for reading a single "character" is [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). As you can see it can be used to read more than one character as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You also can abstract away the whole idea of getting a single character with `streambuf_iterator`s, if you want to use any algorithms:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
  typedef std::istreambuf_iterator<char> buf_iter;
  std::fstream file("name");
  for(buf_iter i(file), e; i != e; ++i){
    char c = *i;
  }
}
```

Comment: After googling a little about iterators, I think this is the right way to go, but I still have a lot of research to do before I fully understand what's going on here.  Thanks for the introduction to iterators.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use standard `for_each` algorithm:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

void handleChar(const char& c)
{
    switch (c) {
        case 'a': // do something
            break;
        case 'b': // do something else
            break;
        // etc.
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("file.txt");
    if (file)
        std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<char>(file),
                      std::istream_iterator<char>(),
                      handleChar);
    else {
        // couldn't open the file
    }
}
```

`istream_iterator` skips whitespace characters. If those are meaningful in your file use `istreambuf_iterator` instead.

Comment: Note that `istream_iterator` will construct a sentry for every token it reads IIRC, which in case of a single `char` can be quite the overhead.

Answer (score 4):

This has already been answered but whatever.
You can use the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) to create a loop which behaves like a for each loop which goes through the entire file reads every character one by one and stop when it's done.

```
char c;
while((file.get(c), file.eof()) == false){
    /*Your switch statement with c*/
}
```

**Explanation**:
The first part of the expression in the for loop `(file.get(c), file.eof())`
will function as follows. Firstly `file.get(c)` gets executed which reads a character and stores the result in `c`. Then, due to the comma operator, the return value is discarded and file.eof() gets executed which returns a bool whether or not the end of the file has been reached. This value is then compared.

**Side Note:**
`ifstream::get()` always reads the next character. Which means calling it twice would read the first two character in the file.

Answer (score 1):

[fstream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/)

Next time you have similar problem go to [cplusplusreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) or similar site, locate [class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) you have problem with and read description of every method. Normally, this solves the problem. Googling also works.

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly just avoid iterators here since it's just hurting readability. Instead, consider:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("sometextfile.txt")

    char c;
    while(file >> c) {
        // do something with c
    }
    // file reached EOF
    return 0;
}
```

This works because the stream implements `operator bool`, which makes it implicitly convertible to true if the stream hasn't reached EOF, and false if it has; and because `file >> c` returns the file itself, it can be used as the while condition.

Using an iterator is only really useful if you intend to use other functions from , but for plain reading, using the stream operator is simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score -2):

```
while (textFile.good()) {
  char a;
  textFile.get(a);
   switch(a)
        {
        case 1:
            //dosomething
              break;
        case ' ':
            //dosomething etc etc
              break;
        case '\n':
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the read be the test in your read loops (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8558959/46642).

Comment: and don't declare automatic variables inside a loop

Comment: @KevinDTimm,  I used to think  earlier the same way, but having studied assembler code generated by modern compilators I saw that they are very clever and allocate memory for such variables BEFORE loop.

Comment: @mikithskegg & @AProgrammer - though `modern compilers` are very clever I'm not willing to make the assumption that this is going to happen.  Additionally, I believe the code I write should correctly imitate what I want to do (and I don't consider recreating a variable on every iteration of a loop to be what I want to do)

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I'd advise to concentrate on big picture instead. Optimal algorithms and code readability are top priority. The "measure before optimizing" principle is for everything else.

Comment: `Concentrate on big picture?` - like not write crappy code? And how does `optimal algorithms` not conflict with `measure before optimizing`?  I started doing this when compilers weren't so smart and so, rather than unlearn good programming practices, I recommend these same practices to other people - because you never know when you're going to have to use a stupid compiler.